# SQL conditional addition or subtraction

Tags: sql

I need an aggregate sum for a table column (grouped by other columns), but with some quantities subtracted rather than added, depending on the value in another column (not in the group or results). Consider the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE Activity (
    wYear SmallInt,
    yMonth SmallInt,
    Account Int,
    Quantity Int,
    Adjustment VarChar(128)
);

INSERT INTO Activity (wYear, yMonth, Account, Quantity, Adjustment)
  VALUES
(2008, 9, 12345, 1000, 'add'),
(2008, 9, 12345, 5000, 'add'),
(2008, 9, 12345, 4000, 'sub'),
(2007, 5, 54321, 1500, 'add')
;
```

I'm looking to total the `Quantity` column for each combination of `wYear, yMonth, Account`, but the quantity should be subtracted (rather than added) if the adjustment is "sub". Summing the quantities for the "add" value is simple:

```
SELECT  wYear, yMonth, Account,  SUM(Quantity) as "Totals"
  FROM  myTable
  WHERE Adjustment = 'add'
  GROUP BY wYear, yMonth, Account
;
```

How do I also subtract quantities for the "sub" adjustments?

Desired results for the sample:

| wYear | yMonth | Account | Totals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2008 | 9 | 12345 | 2000 |
| 2007 | 5 | 54321 | 1500 |

Comment: Answering questions like this is easier if you include create table and insert statements for test data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a case statement to get a positive or negative value depending on the value in Adjustment:

```
select wYear, yMonth, Account, sum(Quantity * case Adjustment when 'Sub' then -1 else 1 end) as "Totals"
from myTable
where Adjustment in ('Add', 'Sub')
group by wYear, yMonth, Account
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT wYear, yMonth, Account, SUM(case when Adjustment  = 'add' then
Quantity when Adjustment = 'sub' then -Quantity else 0 end) as "Totals"
FROM Activity

GROUP BY wYear, yMonth, Account
```

**Test friendly version**

```
Declare @myTable table (wYear int, ymonth int, Account varchar(20), 
Quantity int, Adjustment varchar(20))

Insert into @mytable values (2008, 9, '12345', 1000, 'add')
Insert into @mytable values (2008, 9, '12345', 5000, 'add')
Insert into @mytable values (2008, 9, '12345', 4000, 'sub')
Insert into @mytable values (2007, 5, '54321', 1500, 'add')
 
SELECT wYear, yMonth, Account, SUM(case when Adjustment  = 'add' then
Quantity when Adjustment = 'sub' then -Quantity else 0 end) as "Totals"
FROM @myTable

GROUP BY wYear, yMonth, Account


wYear   yMonth  Account Totals
2007    5   54321   1500
2008    9   12345   2000
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you want:

```
SELECT 
    adds.wYear, 
    adds.yMonth, 
    adds.Account, 
    totals_add - totals_sub AS totals
FROM
(
    SELECT wYear, yMonth, Account, SUM(Quantity) as "totals_add"
    FROM Activity 
    WHERE Adjustment = 'add'
    GROUP BY wYear, yMonth, Account
) adds
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT wYear, yMonth, Account, SUM(Quantity) as "totals_sub"
    FROM Activity 
    WHERE Adjustment = 'sub'
    GROUP BY wYear, yMonth, Account
) subs
ON 
     adds.wYear = subs.wYear 
     AND adds.yMonth = subs.yMonth 
     AND adds.Account = subs.Account
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt its efficiency but this should do the trick

```
SELECT 
    wYear, yMonth, Account, 
    (
      (SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM myTable AS m 
        WHERE m.wYear=wYear AND 
              m.yMonth=yMonth AND 
              m.Account=Account AND 
              m.Adjustment='Add') -
      (SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM myTable AS m 
        WHERE m.wYear=wYear AND 
              m.yMonth=yMonth AND 
              m.Account=Account AND 
              m.Adjustment='Sub')
   ) as "Totals"
FROM Activity 
GROUP BY wYear, yMonth, Account
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this could work -

```
SELECT wYear, yMonth, Account, 
SUM(case when Adjustment = 'sub' then Quantity*-1 else Quantity end) as "Totals"
FROM Activity 
WHERE Adjustment = 'add'
GROUP BY wYear, yMonth, Account
```